# How to end connection in MySQL?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My pseudo code:

```
connection.connect();
 
connection.query('SELECT * FROM post', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO log SET ?', results[0].id, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    
  });
});
 
connection.end();
```

but this return error:

> Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.

If I comment connection.end then script is working well, but the connection does not end. I have to click CTRL + C.

How can I end connection in my example?

Comment: Try `connection.destroy()`.

Comment: @Dougie this not return error, but also this is not working. This stopped script immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this and check if there are any errors:

```
connection.end(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('error:' + err.message);
  }
  console.log('Close the database connection.');
});
```

Moreover, in order to force the connection close immediately:

```
connection.destroy();
```

In order to close the connection after the query finishes, you can use a `Promise` as follows:

```
function insertPosts(connection){
     return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          connection.query('SELECT * FROM post', function (error, results, fields) {
               if (error) reject(error);
               var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO log SET ?', results[0].id, function (error, results, fields) {
                   if (error) reject(error);
               });
          });
     });
}

connection.connect();
insertPosts(connection).then(function() {
   connection.end();  
}).catch((err) => { throw err; });
```

Comment: connection.destroy() not return error, but also this is not working. This stopped script immediately.

Comment: Did any errors show up in the first example? Try using a ``try/catch`` in your code as well.

Comment: If I use connection.destroy, then code with INSERT INTO log SET it is not even execute.

Comment: But then connection will be ended after first execution of loop.

Comment: A suitable solution would be to use a Promise in the query so it waits it to finish and then closes the connection

Comment: Can you give me example?

Comment: @xidag I don't have access to a compiler now, so I added a simple example to the answer. You can research more on the technique and apply it according to your needs